# Is NodaTime too strict to be used in requst DTOs for web APIs?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nodatime

So, I'm developing an API that takes an object which includes datetime properties(ISO 8601).

However, how forgiving should you be when parsing something as ISO 8601?
Ie. an input of `'2023-01-01T00:00Z'` will parse OK with DateTimeOffset, but not when using OffsetDateTime from NodaTime, as it is missing seconds.

I've looked into the OffsetDateTimePattern class, and cannot find any information on this topic. I also tried (and failed) to define a custom pattern that has optional seconds, but I'm not sure
if this is idiomatic nodatime usage anyway. I couldn't find any description on how to do this in the documentation.

So, should I use BCL DateTimeOffset for any exposed data type (request/response DTOs), or can I tweak the NodaTime types to be more forgiving?

Comment: "Simply put, an API should probably accept datetimes (ISO 8601) with any offset, and then you store them as UTC." Is that your specific use-case, or are you asserting that it's always the case? You might want to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/ (That's somewhat aside from the question, but I thought it worth mentioning.)

Comment: A mix maybe :) It's what I'm trying to achieve, but also what I thought was best practice. Thanks for posting that link! 

Side note: the lesson learned in my case is that I should probably have been more specific when documenting the API. The current use case is that I have two clients, and one sends UTC while the other sends with offset. My goal now is to accept this and handle it behind the curtain.

I'm also unsure if "optional seconds" should be accepted or not.

Comment: Note: I reworded the intro to skip the unnecessary statement regarding local/UTC times.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I think the answer stands without any change though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, should I use BCL DateTimeOffset for any exposed data type (request/response DTOs), or can I tweak the NodaTime types to be more forgiving?

You can absolutely create patterns which will allow this. We fairly recently created a change for [LocalDateTimePattern](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/commit/ba3c57d5008fc7e0044fa834f2512fbd673dfc74) to expose such a pattern directly. We haven't (yet) done the same for `OffsetDateTimePattern`, but you can create your own pattern that does this easily enough, with very similar code. I'll admit it's slightly fiddly, but it should do the job.

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

IPattern<OffsetDateTime> pattern = new CompositePatternBuilder<OffsetDateTime>
{
    { OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIso, value => true },
    { OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mmo<G>"),
        value => value.Second == 0 && value.NanosecondOfSecond == 0 },
    { OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HHo<G>"),
        value => value.Minute == 0 && value.Second == 0 && value.NanosecondOfSecond == 0 },
}.Build();

string[] examples =
{
    "2023-01-01T01Z",
    "2023-01-01T01:23Z",
    "2023-01-01T01:23:45Z",
    "2023-01-01T01:23:45.678Z",
    "2023-01-01T01:23:45.678901Z",
    "2023-01-01T01:23:45.678901234Z",
};

foreach (var example in examples)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{example}: {pattern.Parse(example).Success}");
}
```

Once you've created an appropriate `IPattern<OffsetDateTime>`, you may need to configure serialization to use that instead of the default configured pattern. It's hard to provide sample code for that without knowing exactly what's doing the parsing, but [this code in NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.serialization/blob/main/src/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/Extensions.cs#L152) and [the equivalent for NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.serialization/blob/main/src/NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson/Extensions.cs#L91) may be useful.

This will all be a little easier after [this PR](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.serialization/pull/88) is finished and merged...

Comment: Thanks again. I'm marking this as accepted answer, as it shows how the wanted parser pattern can be created. Looking forward to the PR being merged, and maybe an update coming to `OffsetDateTimePattern` as well 